# How to evaluate expressions using Firebase module in the Web Brower of a VueJS application?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am not so familiar with front-end development. I have a simple web app for personal tasks that don't contain any back-end services.

Looking to ensure the security of my website which uses the Firebase Javascript SDK to perform auth/crud on Firebase services directly from the front-end side I'd like to evaluate some expressions in the web browser console in order to ensure that everything is secure.

For now, I am trying to call the Firebase components without performing the authentication, which request I hope will fail due to the User is not authenticated.

I opened the web browser developer tools but when I try to refer to the Firebase module I got `firebase is not defined`. Then, I tried to import the module `import firebase from "@/services/firebase";`, the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at the top level of a module` is returned.

How can I refer to Firebase tools in order to perform evaluate expressions in the web console to check the vulnerabilities?

The screenshots contain the web console and the `Login.vue` which is the component that contains the fields of e-mail/password and a login button.

1. VueJS Login component with Firebase imports.
   [image]
2. My console tries:
   [image]

Suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content (such as error messages and console output). Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot evaluate the firebase modules in web console, as it requires relevant API keys etc to authenticate. You need to use the data in your application to achieve whatever you want to test. It is not possible to import config etc i suppose in the console.